# JQuery UI dialog buttons not displaying right

Tags: css, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I created a new `ASP.NET-MVC 5` project and added the `JQuery UI` `NUGET` package.
I'm trying to follow the [tabs example](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) show in the JQuery website and I can't fugure out why my dialog looks like this:
[image]

and the dialog in the example looks like this (look at the buttons):
[image]

The `HTML` is exactly the same as in the website.
I tried to look for `CSS` and `JS` errors but couldn't find any.
This happens both in FireFox and in IE9.

Comment: @florin.prisecariu the dialog is part of the tabs example

Comment: do you add the buttons when you create the dialog (as js code)?

Comment: @florin.prisecariu nope, I copied the entire thing from JQuery

Answer (score 0):

try to create the dialog buttons like this

```
var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
      Add: function() {
         //some function to describe what happens when clicking on Add
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      Cancel: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
   }
});
```

if you did this and this does not work, try to check if you correctly downloaded the css for the jQuery UI. The button will have classes like "ui-button", "ui-widget".... The buttons do have these classes? If yes, check if there is a css file for them (jquery-ui.css)